# Wizard input - DB View - Dynamic where clause

Tags: python-2.7, openerp-7, odoo

I was trying to pass `where` condition values onto a database view.
`View` was created in `init` method of class defined.
Input to `where` clause was taken from a popped up `wizard`.

Issue is that the wizard form values are `inserted` into model bound database table.
This is happening on all submits.
Currently I am reading the latest record from table on wizard input.
And the view definition is modified to generate result set based on latest input record from wizard table.

```
select v.col1, v.expre2 
  from view_name v, 
       ( select fld1, fld2 from wizrd_tbl_1 order by id desc limit 1 ) as w
 where
       v.colM between w.fld1 and w.fld2
```

Currently I am following the above sequence of steps and results are fetched.
But I think, this would fail if at least two users are using the same wizard concurrently.

How can I change my approach, so that
 1. Wizard input is not sent to database table,
 2. The inputs are sent to a `where` clause dynamically and the result set is bound to a `List View`

---

As a summary, I was trying to:

1. Creates a database view joining multiple table.
2. Take user input ( and saves in db table, which is not expected and
   not required ).
3. Pass the user input to db view's where clause. ( Any alternative to wizard ? )
4. Bind the result set to `List View`

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely a bad idea to morph a database view based on user input, when that view is likely to be accessed by multiple users.

The 'correct' way to do this would be to have a static database view which contains all possible records from the joined tables, and then filter that data for individual users by generating a "domain" and redirecting the user to a tree view with that domain applied.

You can redirect the user by creating a <button type="object"> which calls a function such as the below:

```
def action_get_results(self, cr, uid, ids, context={}):
    # Redirect user to results
    my_domain = ['&', ('col1','=','testval'), ('col2','>',33)]
    return {
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'name': 'Search Results',
        'view_mode': 'tree',
        'res_model': 'your.osv_memory.model.name',
        'target': 'new', # or 'current'
        'context': context,
        'domain': my_domain,
    }
```